# move a lot file in a tree folder in PHP

Tags: php, file, directory, move

I have on my server this organization :
ID/PDF/file.pdf
I would like to have this :
ID/PDF/cont/file.pdf

I have approximately 4000 ID.
So I have a script witch create automatically the folder /cont.

But, I don't know to move the file.pdf.
For example I have :

> 4027/PDF/1.pdf
>  4027/PDF/2.pdf
>  
>  4028/PDF/1.pdf
>   
>  4029/PDF/1.pdf
>  4029/PDF/2.pdf
>  4029/PDF/3.pdf

I would like :

> 4027/PDF/cont/1.pdf
>  4027/PDF/cont/2.pdf
>  
>   4028/PDF/cont/1.pdf
>  
>  4029/PDF/cont/1.pdf
>   4029/PDF/cont/2.pdf
>  4029/PDF/cont/3.pdf

This is my script for create folder:

```
$rqt = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ouvrages');
  while ($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($rqt)) {
   mkdir('ARCHIVE/'.$ID.'/PDF/cont', 0777);
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function not just for renaming but also for moving files and directories. The manual gives this example for moving a file:

```
rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.txt");
```

Comment: ok, but, I don't know the filename. I would like a resquest "all files in this folder type, go to this folder" and not this folder/file go to this folder/file...

Comment: @SebGouaille: you should loop through the files of every directory and perform the move operation on every individual file. You could do this by using [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on the result of [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) or [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier (and faster too!) to rename the whole folder twice:

```
rename('PDF', 'PDF_old');
mkdir('PDF');
rename('PDF_old', 'PDF/cont');
```